# Social-auth-app-django - Error AuthForbidden Your credentials aren't allowed

Tags: python-social-auth

I am using Django 1.9 with python 2.7 and social-auth-app-django (1.2.0). It is part of the Python Social Auth library.

I'm trying to make an authorization through vk.com.
The request for personal data is successful. But after there is a redirection to the country http://127.0.0.1:8000/complete/vk-oauth2/, the error flies: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyqpj.png

Nobody knows what is the reason? Thanks.

Comment: Post full traceback please.

Comment: http://dpaste.com/00CXY11

Comment: omab, Where are you?))  Please, I need you help)

Comment: Could you publish the traceback again on a place that doesn't expire? Also any extra details that you find convenient, like OAuth2 scopes, are you calling any API endpoint?

Comment: [traceback](http://my-files.ru/sf4kwk)

I request permission to receive mail SOCIAL_AUTH_VK_OAUTH2_SCOPE = ['email'], but even without this, I get the same error.

Comment: omab, any ideas?